# What was the importance of Dr. Bower's attempts to purchase Brewdog's Pink IPA, both successful and unsuccessful, to his claim?

Tags: england-and-wales, discrimination, equality-act-2010

Could [his claim](https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/brewdog-man-sues-court-case-pink-ipa-beer-for-girls-gender-pay-gap-a8963521.html) still have been successful if he had only presented a printed advertisement showing the sexist promotional pricing scheme?

To put it another way, if a black man took a picture of a sign outside a business that said "no blacks, no dogs, no Irish," would he have the right to claim discrimination, or would he have to actually enter the premises and try to be served, and then be refused service, in order to have a valid claim?

Answer (score 2):

### You must have a sufficient connection to the harm

One of the key factors for taking legal action is the concept of [standing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_(law)).

Standing is complicated, but, in brief, the act or omission complained of must be one that directly harms you (the "something to lose" doctrine), you are reasonably related to the situation (the "chilling effect" doctrine), or the law explicitly grants standing.

The advertisement would probably be sufficient since, as a member of the discriminated-against class, the advertisement was directed at him. His damages would likely have been less as he did not suffer the "humiliation" described by the court.